# Annoying lag when AVQueuePlayer jumps from asset to another

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, mpmovieplayercontroller, avqueueplayer

I have an `AVQueuePlayer` that is supposed to play sequentially an array of `AVURLAsset` representing consecutive fragments of one continuous video.

**Whenever a fragment ends and another starts, there is a small glitch that can be well noticed (frame hold for approx 0.2sec and sound gets muted)**

I tried researching how to get around that issue but haven't found anything. I tried solving it by having 2 `AVQueuePlayer`'s and switch between both around 0.2sec before the end of every fragment. Issue not solved.

Any idea on how to solve that?

*Note: When joining the mp4 fragments together using an mp4 joiner software, the output is a single smooth video without any glitch.*

Comment: does this answer help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659404/avfoundation-play-consecutive-video-fragments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Been through this exactly. You will experience that glitch no matter what you do. Reason being how `AVQueuePlayer` works. It loads the next item when the previous ends. So if your videos are big, you may also see that blank screen for 2-3 seconds. One solution is what you mentioned, i.e. using two `AVQueuePlayer`. But as you said its not working for you, and even if you make it work, it will be clumsy.

A better and clean solution is `AVMutableComposition`. It may look complex at first but its fast and one time task. You create a composition of all of your videos and play it in a simple `AVPlayer`. And in your case, I assume you just have to play it, so you don't even have to export it.

To know how to use `AVMutableComposition`, go through this [link](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/11/10/Video-Stitching-With-AVFoundation.html). It will explain with exact code you need.

Answer (score -1):

As you said, "2 AVQueuePlayers" way still has problem(some sound glitch).
I faced same problem and solved it by using HLS.

You can play local TS files.

At first, make m3u8 and TS files from original movie file.

e.g.

```
mediafilesegmenter -t 10 sample.mp4
```

Then, add resource files to iOS device. You can add files from iTunes, add as resource, or make download function and get from your app.

Run a http server, and then pass the local URL to AVPlayerController. I used cocoaHttpServer.

I put simple example here.

https://github.com/satoshi0212/samples/tree/master/TSPlaySample